# How to use the /pack_data RPC endpoint to pack a map

Tags: rpc

To pack an address with the `/pack_data` we pass the following:

```
const packedData = await axios.post(
      `${nodeURL}/chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/scripts/pack_data`,
      {
        data: { string: "tz1SaUEpoM8ME55RdMbNifypEqETodYKyNBD" },
        type: { prim: 'address' },
        gas: '800000'
      },
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }
    )
```

What about packing a map, for example:

```
const myMap = {
      fieldOne: 2,
      fieldTwo: "tz1SaUEpoM8ME55RdMbNifypEqETodYKyNBD"
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, what is the source language you're using? The example you give, `myMap` is not a map in the Michelson sense, as the types of the bindings are different (`fieldOne` is an integer, and `fieldTwo` is an address). I would rather call this type of structure a record, which has no direct equivalent in Michelson. However, it could be encoded as a pair: `pair int address` where each component corresponds to each field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This RPC expects to receive a Michelson data value and type in its JSON representation. I'm unsure what source language you are using, but you can cheat a little bit and find out the JSON representation of a Michelson value and type by using the `tezos-client hash data` command. By adding the `-l` flag, you also see the RPC calls made by the client.

For instance, if your record is encoded as a pair:

```
$ tezos-client -l hash data '(Pair 2 "tz1SaUEpoM8ME55RdMbNifypEqETodYKyNBD")' of type 'pair int address'

...

>>>>3: http://localhost:18731/chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/scripts/pack_data
  { "data":
      { "prim": "Pair",
        "args":
          [ { "int": "2" },
            { "string": "tz1SaUEpoM8ME55RdMbNifypEqETodYKyNBD" } ] },
    "type":
      { "prim": "pair",
        "args": [ { "prim": "int" }, { "prim": "address" } ] },
    "gas": "1040000" }
...
```

Comment: Thak you!! That's very helpful! Can you please tell me how to pack a map that contains the same type in values: {key1: "wordOne", key2: "wordTwo"}?

Comment: It's: 

tezos-client -l hash data '{Elt "aaaa" "ddddd"; Elt "mamma" "mammaaaa"}' of type 'map string string'

Thank you an other time.